# Rails: Two instance variables or just one and create another one in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, controller

I have a doubt of good manners in Rails and I believe MVC in general.  I have a controller which retrieves some objects from a model given a particular condition.  I need those objects in the view, and I also need a particular data structure with attributes of those objects.  That data structure is like this:

```
[[object1.attr1, object1.attr2],[object2.attr2,object2.attr2],...]
```

My question is:

Should I create two instance variables in the controller: one with all the objects retrieved from the model, and another one with the data structure created from the attributes of those objects or should I just create one instance variable with all the objects and create that data structure in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move some of your code out of your views to:

1. a **view helper**
2. the **controller**
3. the **model**

A **Rails Helper** (opt. 1) seem more appropriate for your case. If you need for example to populate a select tag an helper with a method that returns `options_for_select(...your complex structure formatted)` would be the right choice.

You can use `options_for_select` (from the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html)) this way

`<%= options_for_select([[object1.attr1, object1.attr2],[object2.attr2,object2.attr2],...], 2) %>` will become:

```
<option value="object1-attr2-value">object1-attr1-value</option>
<option value="object2-attr2-value" selected="selected">object2.attr1-value</option>
...
```

You can add that method inside the **ApplicationHelper** (if it needs to be application wide) or in a model specific helper:

```
# app/helpers/...the helper you choose
def options_for_your_complex_select(default_state)
  options_for_select( [[object1.attr1, object1.attr2],[object2.attr2,object2.attr2],...],
                  default_state )
end
```

and the use this helper in your views this way (please choose a better method name than mine :) ): `<%= select_tag :state, options_for_your_complex_select(params[:default_state]) %>`

This will help you make your code more manageable and your view more readable.
[Rails **best practices** website](http://rails-bestpractices.com/) has more on this. See how **move your code** in a [ViewHelper](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/26-move-code-into-helper), [Model](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/25-move-code-into-model) and [Controller](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/24-move-code-into-controller).

If you have to deal with a lot of attributes, this [screencast about the draper gem](http://railscasts.com/episodes/286-draper) by @ryanb explain how to simplify your views.

Answer (score 2):

It depends, but you shouldn't create data structures in the view.

Either do it in a controller function, or if it's tightly coupled to the model, in the model. From the limited description it sounds like this belongs in the model, but it's hard to say.

Comment: Dave Newton how do you decide if it should be in model or controller? This data structure is to generate option tags for a select for all those objects.

Comment: Generally speaking, DATA belongs in the model.  The only thing that should really show up in your controller are any search options/model update attributes that might come in through the get/post parameters.  If you're using it to generate options tags, look in to the rails helpers.